# (JsFiddle) Knockout observable shows different value in binding on screen to console.log

Tags: knockout.js

During investigation for another problem, I've discovered a really weird phenomenon where a `<span>` bound to an observable shows "true" whereas clicking a button that runs a function to log it to the console window shows "false"!

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/fbc0w39w/1/

Click on green button, use F12 in chrome to show console window, click on "log it" and see "true" in the console.  You'll also see "true" just below the submit button.  Then clear down the text in user login, click elsewhere (value updates on blur) and see the error message on the login box. The value below the submit button stays as true.  Click on "log it" button again and voila!  It logs "False" as it should do.

Both values are coming from the vo.isValid variable as far as I can tell...?

Comment: Sorry, had wrong link there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the problem: in your `getData` function, you're replacing the entire `validatedObservable` with a new one. The two bottom UI elements are bound to the old one's `isValid` observable.

I'm not sure what the "right" way of using the `validationObservable` is (never used it), but you can see that it's a problem by nesting it in an observable:

```
self.vo = ko.observable(ko.validatedObservable());

self.getData = function() {
  self.selectedUser(ko.mapping.fromJS(data, validationMapping));
  self.vo(ko.validatedObservable(self.selectedUser(), {deep: true, live: true, observable: true}));
};
```

So you'd probably want to find a way to make sure the `validatedObservable` just reacts to changes in `selectedUser` without instantiating new ones.

Here's a "working" fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/st5e0r1o/

Comment: Weirdly enough I've just been looking at that too. I tried directly replacing the existing observable (as you've shown) but now both onscreen and console.log don't show the error... I suppose it's progress of a sort!

Comment: Ah, just seen that you've cured it by putting in the observable. Didn't realise it at first.  I'm not experienced with using validation so it's all new to me.